# javascript: function call via constructor vs function call directly

Tags: javascript

```
function test(){
  this.name = 'My function';
}
let a = test();
let b = new test(); // Is affect on performance,memory?
```

Call the function directly and call via constructor.
What is the diffrence between?

Comment: log the value of `this` in both calls and observe the difference.

Comment: It is not a matter of performance. They are fundamentally different. Just `console.log(a,b)`, you will see `a` is undefined while `b` is the constructed object. `test()` invokes a function and returns the return value of the function. `new text()` create an object, like creating an instance of a class.

Comment: a will return undefined. and if you try calling a.name it will throw an uncaught typeerror. So b is the way to go for this example